# HML5 / JS version of the "WordPress Audio Player?"

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, wordpress, html, html5-video

I like the presentation that the "[WordPress Audio Plugin](http://wpaudioplayer.com/)" makes for playing audio content for blogs, etc.: 
[image]

(Example: http://maestric.com/shared/jquery_audio_player/example3.html)

However this is a Flash based player and obviously does not work well for iOS devices.  Is there a version or something exceptionally similar written purely for HTML5 / JS? I'm hoping to accomplish the same style of playing and compact presentation where it starts compacted and then expands out like this upon play.

A JPlayer theme may be perfect for this, but I'm not really seeing a solution after a lot of digging about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still have not found a solution to this one matching my spec initially stated, but this is a bit closer: http://www.brianhadaway.com/html5-audio-player-with-flash-fallback/

Will accept a good answer once one's posted, but for now this is more inline with what I'm hunting for.

Answer (score 0):

Loo into [jPlayer](http://jplayer.org/latest/demos/) or [Speakker](http://www.speakker.com/). You can always [build your own](http://neutroncreations.com/blog/building-a-custom-html5-audio-player-with-jquery/) too.